# Flink dies; OutOfMemory in Directr Buffer Memory

Tags: out-of-memory, apache-flink

While deploying Flink, I got the following OOM error messages:

> org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.exception.LocalTransportException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
>       at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestClientHandler.exceptionCaught(PartitionRequestClientHandler.java:153)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:246)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224)
>       at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.exceptionCaught(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:131)
>
> Caused by: io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
>       at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:234)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
>       ... 9 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
>       at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:658)
>       at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.(DirectByteBuffer.java:123)
>       at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:311)

I set 'taskmanager.network.numberOfBuffers: 120000' in flink-conf file, but it doesn't work.

Number of TaskManger: **50**, Memory per TaskManager: **16GB**, Cores per TaskManager: **16**, Number of Slots per TasmNager: **8**

For the job I ran, I used Parallelism as 25 and the raw data file is about 300GB and there are lots of join operations, which, I guess, requires lots of network communications.

Please let me know if you have any idea about what's going on here

Comment: Did you have a look at https://flink.apache.org/faq.html#i-got-an-outofmemoryexception-what-can-i-do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of Flink are you using?
Flink 0.10.0 and 0.10.1 have an issue with an upgraded Netty version. This issue was fixed about 3 three weeks ago and not yet available in a release.

It is fixed in the [master](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master) branch (published as 1.0-SNAPSHOT) or the [0.10](https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/release-0.10) branch.

Comment: I downloaded the latest master branch, compiled and it works now! Thanks